# setting view's background image in iphone

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, background-color

Can I set an image for the view's own background image? I don't want to use UIImageView control. It seems not to be possible using IB. Do I have to do it programatically?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

What a waste of resources, use :

```
[[self view] setBackgroundColor: [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]]];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"plain_bg.png"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with UIImageView? This is a perfect use for it.

Comment: the problem is putting other controls (such as text fields and buttons etc.) over the image view control. how can i send this imageview to the back side (and make it passive) so that my main controls can be used efficiently.

Comment: In interface builder, select the image view and then select "Send to Back" from the Layout menu.

Comment: anyway, my question is like that. there is a hyperlink (titled "forgot your username / password?") and a label on the view. i used a round rect button for the hypelink. but i don't want that button's boundries can be seen. (it should be seen like hyperlink) Alpha level doesn't work the way i want. button should be displayed over imageview just like a hiperlink. could i express my trouble correctly? sory for that.

Comment: sory but i couldn't find "Send to Back"

Comment: briefly, how can i represent a hyperlink on the uiimageview (like in a web page) and label without rectangle

Answer (score 0):

I really don't think that using backgroundColor in this way is the proper way to do things. Personally, I would create a UIImageView and insert it into your view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIColor *background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pic.png"]];
self.view.backgroundColor = background;
```

Try this
Its working for me